# How #P is easier than PSPACE?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, turing-machines

It is said that #P is not harder than PSPACE. This way, how can Alternating Turing machine solve #SAT in polynomial time?

And if it can, seems, that it takes at least $O(n^4)$ time which is more time than needed for TQBF.

Comment: I think the common correction to this question would be "how can an alternating turing machine solve a decision problem version of #SAT" ,and the decision version is usually "are there at least K solutions?".

Answer (score 0):

> This way, how can Alternating Turing machine solve #SAT in polynomial time?

An alternating Turing machine can only solve decision problems, so that questions makes sense for the decision variant of $\text{#SAT}$:

$$\text{Input: Boolean Formula $F$, $k \in \mathbb N$. Question: Are there at least $k$ solutions for $F$?}$$

This decision variant is in $\text{P}^\text{#P}$ ($\text{P}$ with $\text{#P}$ oracle), because you only need to ask the oracle how many solutions there are and compare the answer to $k$.
It is proven that:
$$\text{P}^\text{#P} \subseteq \text{PSPACE} = \text{AP}$$
So there exists indeed an alternating Turing machine solving the decision variant of $\text{#SAT}$ in polynomial time.

> And if it can, seems, that it takes at least $\mathcal O(n^4)$ time which is more time than needed for TQBF.

Reference? That still wouldn't mean that the decision variant of $\text{#SAT}$ is harder than $\text{TQBF}$.

The term $A$ is not harder than $B$ is in this context defined as $A \le^p_m B$. That means there exists a polynomial time reduction from $A$ to $B$.

$\text{TQBF}$ is $\text{PSPACE}$-complete so from every decision problem in $\text{PSPACE}$ there exists a polynomial time reduction to $\text{TQBF}$.

Calculating the polynomial time reduction from the decision variant of $\text{#SAT}$ to $\text{TQBF}$ might already use more time than actually solving the resulting $\text{TQBF}$-instance (on an alternating Turing machine).

Comment: How #SAT is reducible to TQBF? Let's see function of 8 literals. Yes, I can run a TQBF as tautology first, if it is not true, than amount of solutions is less than 255. Then I need to change one quantifier. So, I'll run 8 TQBF's where only 1 at time is ∃-quantifier. This was 1 step - 8 formulas. Than for all of those 8 TQBF's which are false, I'll need to add second quantifier. Worst case is all of them are false. Second step is 56 formulas. Such reduction takes more than 2^n time and I can't see any better than brute-force.

Comment: I don't know how that polynomial time reduction looks like, but it MUST exist because it is proven that $\text{TQBF}$ is $\text{PSPACE}$-complete. Added that to the answer. The proof is constructive so you get the reduction from it. It's a complicated one but computable in polynomial time.

Comment: I only found a proof that **#P = #PSPACE**. Also, there is some evidence, that #QBF is harder than TQBF since ∃ and ∀ can be expressed as counting quantifiers.

Comment: So, if #P is inside PSPASE, #PSPACE is inside PSPACE too? Weird.

Comment: Do you have a reference for $\text{#P} = \text{#PSPACE}$?

Comment: Only cached version found since it returns error without cache.http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:R2WBEOPTw50J:web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/sharp-p-pspace.pdf

Comment: In the proof he even showed that #QBF is equally hard as #SAT. If the proof is correct, then yes, $\text{P}^\text{#PSPACE} \subseteq \text{PSPACE}$. But it is trivial that $\text{PSPACE} \subseteq \text{P}^\text{#PSPACE}$. Altogether that would mean $\text{P}^\text{#P} = \text{PSPACE}$, so I suggest the proof is wrong.

Comment: And $P^{\texttt{#}PSPACE}$ contains ${\texttt{#}PSPACE$? Or vice versa? Also, count number of solutions (or even say whether there is more than $n$ solutions) for TQBF is harder than solve TQBF. Because TQBF is equal to #QBF asking whether there is at least 1 solution. Since that TQBF is a subcase of #QBF.

Comment: Where can I see a proof for $P^\text{#P} \subseteq PSPACE$?

Comment: The proof is easy. You can simulate the $\text{#P}$ oracle in polynomial space: Given a $\text{NP}$ turing machine $M$ and input $w$, search every computational path of $M$ on $w$ after each other (and count accepting paths). Storing the information which path you went the last time needs max. $\log_22^{p(|w|)} = p(|w|)$ space and storing the configuration also needs max. $p(|w|)$ space because $M$ can't use more than polynomial space. This proof method doesn't work on $\text{PSPACE}$ turing machines because they can use exponential time.

Comment: Number of paths is exponential and it is proved that simulating all possible paths for polynomial Turing machine takes exponential time. I have found that Toda's Theorem implies that $PH \subseteq P^\text{#P}$ and nothing about upper bound of such machine.

Comment: So what? We were talking about polynomial space...

Comment: Yes, it takes exponential time on polynomial space machine to simulate all possible configurations of another polynomial time space machine. Simplier, one computer can't predict all possible outputs of another computer.

Comment: I know that but what does it have to do with $\text{P}^\text{#P} \subseteq \text{#PSPACE}$? We just need to simulate the $\text{#P}$-oracle in deterministic polynomial space. That is allowed to take exponential time.

Comment: Your proof says that $P^\text{#P}$ takes polynomial space which is not equivalent to $PSPACE$ definition. $PSPACE$ only contain decision problems. And I believe #SAT-decision is not there since #QBF-decision is not there also. And of course, if #SAT-decision computable in polynomial time, then #SAT is also computable in polynomial time with one order of magnitude increase. Just by use of the bisection method.

Comment: You obviously don't know what $P^\text{#P}$ is. It's the class of decision problems decidable by a deterministic turing machin **with $\text{#P}$ oracle** in polynomial time.

Comment: $\text{#P}$ oracle returns decision for #SAT in constant time, if I understand it right. Possible task for such machine is to find number of solutions for system of several formulae which don't share any literals.

Comment: Correct. And we can simulate that oracle on a deterministic turing machine **without oracle** in polynomial space (We need to simulate it deterministically because it's a function). Because we can do that, we can also simulate a whole $\text{P}^\text{#P}$ turing machine in polynomial space, because it can only use polynomial space itself and ask the oracle.

Comment: But that's all about space complexity. Speaking about time complexity, I'm sure that $PP$ is **much** easier than $\text{#}P$. Also, I know how to solve MAJSAT on ATM.